# Extract and merge non duplicated data from 2 columns on excel with formula

Tags: excel, date, extract, mergesort, array-merge

I'm trying to merge 2 date columns (contains blanks cells) and extract the non-duplicates excluding the blank cells while sorted in ascending order.

However, I'm encountering error trying to do so. As excel took in the blank cells as data and extracted data in the end contains invalid info that were not found in either columns. The extracted data were not sort correctly too.

| S1 Date | S1 Count | S2 Date | S2 Count | Overall Date | Overall Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2021 | 56 | 01/10/2021 | 127 | 01/10/2021 | 183 |
| 02/10/2021 | 98 | 02/10/2021 | 125 | 02/10/2021 | 223 |
| 03/10/2021 | 122 | 03/10/2021 | 51 | 03/10/2021 | 173 |
| 04/10/2021 | 45 | 04/10/2021 | 54 | 04/10/2021 | 99 |
| 05/10/2021 | 81 | 05/10/2021 | 64 | 05/10/2021 | 145 |
| 06/10/2021 | 21 | 06/10/2021 | 87 | 06/10/2021 | 108 |
| 07/10/2021 | 84 | 07/10/2021 | 63 | 07/10/2021 | 147 |
| 08/10/2021 | 12 | 08/10/2021 | 79 | 08/10/2021 | 91 |
| 09/10/2021 | 63 | 09/10/2021 | 45 | 09/10/2021 | 108 |
| 10/10/2021 | 79 | 10/10/2021 | 81 | 10/10/2021 | 160 |
| 11/10/2021 | 65 | 11/10/2021 | 21 | 11/10/2021 | 86 |
| 12/10/2021 | 81 | 12/10/2021 | 121 | 12/10/2021 | 202 |
| 20/10/2021 | 71 | 14/10/2021 | 54 | 20/10/2021 | 204 |
| 21/10/2021 | 83 | 15/10/2021 | 97 | 21/10/2021 | 151 |
| 22/10/2021 | 127 | 16/10/2021 | 67 | 22/10/2021 | 205 |
| 23/10/2021 | 84 | 17/10/2021 | 98 | 23/10/2021 | 137 |
| 24/10/2021 | 121 | 18/10/2021 | 54 | 24/10/2021 | 144 |
| 25/10/2021 | 54 | 19/10/2021 | 62 | 25/10/2021 | 54 |
| 26/10/2021 | 58 | 20/10/2021 | 133 | 26/10/2021 | 58 |
| 27/10/2021 | 87 | 21/10/2021 | 68 | 27/10/2021 | 87 |
| 28/10/2021 | 64 | 22/10/2021 | 78 | 28/10/2021 | 102 |
| 29/10/2021 | 34 | 23/10/2021 | 53 | 29/10/2021 | 109 |
| 30/10/2021 | 120 | 24/10/2021 | 23 | 30/10/2021 | 184 |
| 31/10/2021 | 78 | 28/10/2021 | 38 | 31/10/2021 | 78 |
|  |  | 29/10/2021 | 75 | **00/01/1900** | 0 |
|  |  | 30/10/2021 | 64 | **14/10/2021** | 54 |
|  |  |  |  | **15/10/2021** | 97 |
|  |  |  |  | **16/10/2021** | 67 |
|  |  |  |  | **17/10/2021** | 98 |
|  |  |  |  | **18/10/2021** | 54 |
|  |  |  |  | **19/10/2021** | 62 |

[Excel image- Error highlighted in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRn1D.png)

The formula used was `=SORT(IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(DateS1,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$3:F3,DateS1),0)),INDEX(DateS2,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$3:F3,DateS2),0))),""))`

Really appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Windows Excel, I suggest a different formula:

```
Data Range: G1:J100
L1: overallDate
L2: =SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,INDEX(G2:I100,SEQUENCE(99),{1,3}))&"</s></t>","//s")))
M2: =IF(L2="","", SUMIF($G$1:$G$100,L2,$H$1:$H$100)+SUMIF($I$1:$I$100,L2,$J$1:$J$100))
```

*Results from `L2` will `SPILL` down as far as needed*
*In `L2` adjust the range reference and `SEQUENCE` count as appropriate for your data, or make them dynamic*
*Formula in `M2` will need to be copied down*

***Edit: If you want an inclusive list of dates in the OverallDate column, consider:***

```
L2: =LET(dates,INDEX(G2:I100,SEQUENCE(99),{1,3}),MIN(dates)-1 + SEQUENCE(1+MAX(dates)-MIN(dates)))
```

[image]